# Worship someone as a sign of love, respect, etc

Tags: word-usage

In my mother language when someone tends to imply that they respect or love someone else too much, they can figuratively say e.g:

> - I worship my mother / my husband, etc.

Does it sound natural in English to say the same thing or does it sound idiomatically unnatural? I would be really thankful if you let me know the most natural equivalent in English if it doesn't work.

Comment: To say you "worship" your partner as a (hetero) man sounds clingy and strange, as a woman, it sounds possibly abusive. I wouldn't say ig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Worship* would be felt odd here, because it implies not only love but deep reverence. However, *adore* (which originally meant the same thing as *worship*) has mostly lost its religious sense and may be used to express extravagant affection.

Comment: Thank you very much StoneyB. So you mean that it would not sound idiomatically unnatural to say something like: "I adore my mother / my teacher / my wife etc." Right? :)

Comment: @A-friend Yes, that's fine. It may be mere exaggeration, or it may be qualified: "I adore my professor, *but* ..."

Answer (score 6):

The following expression is idiomatic, and would not sound out of place.

- I really love my mother. In fact you could say, I **worship the ground she walks on**

> **worship the ground sb walks on**
>   to love and admire someone very much:
>   *I worship the ground you walk on - you must know that by now.*
>
> *[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worship-the-ground-sb-walks-on)*

Comment: This phrase has the implication "she can do no wrong". It is often used of others who fail to see a person's faults: *He worships the ground she walks on.*

Comment: @TRomano Good point, but it's often just a hyperbolic statement. It probably explains why I've never heard my son say this about me to anyone. But who knows, maybe in private :)

Comment: But he might adore you, even if he does not worship the ground you walk on.

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer, only with the Cambridge definition.

Comment: @TRomano it was a toss up between Cambridge and Macmillan's definition: [*to love and admire someone so much that you think they are perfect*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/worship-the-ground-someone-walks-on)

Comment: Macmillan's is the better definition, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider [idolize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idolize)

> Admire, revere, or love greatly or excessively.
>
> ‘he idolized his mother’

The word "idol" itself of course does have some original religious connotations

> an image or representation of a god used as an object of worship.

But it is mostly used in a secular sense these days (e.g. Pop idol)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is idiomatic and commonplace (BrE).

When spoken aloud, there is usually an almost ironic emphasis on the word *worship*, as if to proclaim that you know it's a very strong thing to say and indeed mean it that way.